# 都 vs 也 in "连。。。都／也" structure

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference

I would like to learn when to use 都 and when to use 也 in the 连。。。都／也 structure.

My current understanding is that 都 is often used for positive sentences whereas 也 is generally used for negative sentences, e.g.

他 什么 都 吃，连 狗肉 都 吃。
我们 连 一 次 也 没 见 过。

However, I can see many exceptions to this 'rule'. Any more hints on when to use 都 or 也? Does it matter in general?

Thank you!

Comment: ＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂也（副）／都（副）  **［相同］**  都是副词，作状语，可以表示强调。以下情况可以互换：  **１.**  用在＂连。。。都／也。。。＂的格式中，或隐含＂连＂字表示强调语气的句子中：（１）中午的饭，他连一口也没吃。（都✓）（２）老张气得一句话也说不出来。（都✓）（３）他紧张得连自我介绍都望了。（也✓）（４）你太胆小了，树叶掉下来都怕砸破脑袋。（也✓）（５）你怎么连他都不认识？（也✓）  **２。**  都可以用在表示任指，总括的句子中，常用＂无论、不管、谁、什么、哪里＂等配合：（１）大家沉默着，谁也不说话。（都✓）（２）他什么事也不问，什么事也不管。（都✓）（３）我哪里也不去，就在家看书。（都✓）（４）无论困难再大，我都不怕。（也✓）（５）无论事情怎么复杂，我们都得想办法解决。（也✓）（６）你这么做，不管出于什么理由，都不能原谅。（也✓）  **３。**  都可以用在＂一。。。都／也。。。＂的格式中：（１）老林向来一粒粮食也不浪费。（都✓）（２）关于赛车方面的知识，我一点都不懂。（也✓）  **４。**  都可以用在＂V都／也V。。。＂的格式中：（１）他累得爬也爬不动了。（都✓）（２）他又急又气，哭都哭不出来了。（也✓）  **[不同］**  **１。**  ＂都＂可以和＂无论＋选择格式／正反格式＂配合，表示强调：＂也＂不能：

Comment: （１）无论去云南还是去西藏，我都和你一起去。（选择格式，也✗）（２）无论流行歌曲还是民歌，我都喜欢。（选择格式，也✗）（３）无论去不去，我都会通知你。（正反格式，也✗）（４）无论你同意不同意，我都要去。（正反格式，也✗）       ..  **２.**  ＂也＂可以和＂即使、虽然＂配合，用在表示让步或转折的句子中，表示强调：＂都＂不能：（１）即使你不说，我也知道。（都✗）（２）即使失败了，也没有关系。（都✗）（３）我虽然没见过，可也听人说过。（都✗）  **３。**  ＂也＂还可以用在并列复句的后一分句，表示跟前面的情况相同；＂都＂不能：我要去天津，也要去北京。（都✗）（２）他昨天来了，今天也来了。（都✗）（３）安娜会唱京剧，阿里也会唱京剧。（都✗）  **４。**  ＂也＂可以组成＂也。。。，也。。。＂的句式，表示并列的行为、情况；＂都＂无此用法：（１）饭也吃了，酒也喝了，我该告辞了。（都✗）（２）小王也走了，小李也走了，朋友们都走了。（都✗）（３）他左想也不对，右想也不对，实在不知道怎么办好。（都✗）（４）你这也不吃，那也不吃，到底想吃什么？（都✗）  **５。**  ＂都＂可以用在单句中，表示总括，相当于＂全＂；还可以用在数量短语，表示强调，有＂已经＂的意思：（１）我们全家都喜欢吃橘子。（总括，也✗）（２）这些都是我的衣服。（总括，也✗）

Comment: （３）天都亮了，快起床吧。（强调，也✗）（４）他今年都３０岁了。（强调，也✗）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

连...都... and 连...也... are interchangeable as a structure. In fact, in the structure 连...都..., 都, as an adverb, means 也!

In your case, the sentence could be rephrased as

> 他什么都吃，连狗肉 **也** 吃。 我们连一次 **都** 没见过。

However, in the first sentence, 他什么都吃, 都 can not be replaced by 也. Here, 都 means 'all'.