# Does 都 refers to the 天天 or to the 晚上 in the following sentence?

Tags: simplified-characters

Does 都 refers to the 天天 or to the 晚上 in the following sentence:

> 天天晚上都很忙

Comment: 天天、晚上、都 all are adverbial adjuncts (状语），都 being an adverb (副词）modifying the adjective predicate (形容词谓语）head word （中心语）很忙, (if it were not automatic, some might even say 很 also is a 状语）

Comment: Why to use 都 here at all. How does it affect the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: see https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/26698/%e9%83%bd-vs-%e4%b9%9f-in-%e8%bf%9e-%e9%83%bd-%e4%b9%9f-structure esp.comments, it seems 都 as part of the predicate has to be viewed as applying to the rest of it
including 天天晚上

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**天天晚上** is a single set phrase meaning every night.

**都** refers to it [each evening].

Thus we have: [I'm] very busy every night.

Answer (score 1):

天天晚上都很忙

he do is very busy in the evening everyday

(does english has this sentence? may be you can modify to a even fitable sentence)

天天 is just like everyday

晚上 is evening.

都  is do . it represent the empathize the work is busy

Answer (score 0):

"天天" has the same meaning as "每天". Because "天" is a classifier, "都" here refers to "晚上".

You can see the details [here](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22every%22_with_%22mei%22).

Answer (score 0):

The word 都 refers to 每天晚上 or 天天晚上, or you may consider it refers to 晚上 not 天天. We repeat **somethings** (a one-character noun) for "every **somethings**" in Chinese, like 天天, is the same as 每天, which means **everyday**, also you may speak 人人 for 每个人, and 月月, 年年, etc. You may repeat Chinese **measure word** as well, like 个个 means **each one**, **every one**, 条条(大道) means **all (roads)**, 次次 means **every time**. You may also speak 一个个(人), which means **(persons) one by one**, and 一条条(鱼), 一栋栋(大楼), 一辆辆(车), etc.